# Perl (Dancer) & Template Toolkit - looping thru hashref

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, dancer

I'm using Perl with [Dancer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer) and [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/).

I'm passing a hashref to my template.

This is the way it's built, out of an array (`@musicList`):

```
my $hashrMusic = {};
my $intCount = 0;

foreach my $track ( @musicList ) {
    $hashrMusic->{ $intCount } = $track;
    $intCount++ ;
}
```

This is the `Dumper` version of the hash:

```
 $VAR1 = {
      '1049' => '09 Faruk\'s Funk (Matt Stein + Nickodemus Rework).mp3',
      '127' => '45 There She Goes.mp3',
      '71' => 'Kenny Wayne Shepherd - One Foot On The Pass.mp3'
        };
```

This is the way I pass the hashref to the template:

```
template 'scan.tt', {
    'countTracks' => scalar keys %$hashrMusic,
    'tracks' => $hashrMusic,
    'dump' => Dumper($hashrMusic),
}
```

Now I'm trying to loop through the hasref to display it, using the following TT code:

```
          <ul>
            <% FOREACH track IN tracks %>
              <li><% track.value %></li>
            <% END %>
          </ul>
```

This produces no output (but `countTracks` is OK, just as `dump`). Any hint/idea?

Comment: `<ul>
            <% FOREACH track IN tracks.keys.nsort %>
              <li><% track.filename %>
            <% END %>
          </ul>`

Comment: @jlareau, doesn't work neither. In your proposed solution, `track` should be the key, but it's empty. `<ul> <% FOREACH i IN tracks.keys.nsort %> <li> <% $i %> </ul>` doesn't work neither.

Comment: Why are you using the $ sign?

Comment: Try: foreach track in tracks and then use track.filename

Comment: I'm using the $ sign just as in the following Dancer doc: https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Tutorial#Our-first-route-handler

Comment: I tried your proposed `foreach` loop: it prints `HASH(0x7f80b4cd9a58)` and that's it. Once again, it does not go through the hashref..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dancer is not using TemplateToolkit by default, but a look-like template engine that does not support TT tags.
Digging in the config files and configuring the template engine to be TT solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing /li.  Also you're misusing FOREACH with respect to hashrefs.

Try this:

```
 <ul>
   <% FOREACH track IN tracks %>
     <li>
       The key is: <% track.key %>
       The filename is: <% track.value.filename %>
     </li>
   <% END %>
 </ul>
```

For complete documentation on FOREACH, go here:

http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_FOREACH

Comment: Thanks for point the <li> issue. Your solution only prints the hashref (HASH(0x7f83d196fd40)), and nothing more. I tried to simplify the hash itself:
$VAR1 = {
          '1049' => '09 Faruk\'s Funk (Matt Stein + Nickodemus Rework).mp3',
          '127' => '45 There She Goes.mp3',
          '71' => 'Kenny Wayne Shepherd - One Foot On The Pass.mp3'
}
And I used `track.value` instead of `track.value.filename`, with the same result :(

Comment: Can you post your assignment to $musicFiles?

Comment: Also, do you see the right number of iterations (3 in the example you posted) and do you see "The key is: ..." and "The filename is: "...

Comment: I edited the question to add the assignment of the hashref. The TT loop actually does not loop: there's only one iteration (and the output is between the <ul> and the <li> tags).